# Prove that $a^2+\dfrac{1}{a^a-a+1}\ge a+1$, for any number $a$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, induction, factoring

> Prove that $a^2+\dfrac{1}{a^a-a+1}\ge a+1$, for any number $a$

I think I can solve the problem by putting all the variables on one side and then $0$ on the other side, then factoring the side with the variables to become a square. This proves the inequality because anything squares is positive. Can I solve this problem using algebra? Obviously you can solve it using induction.

Comment: Induction? Is $a$ here a natural number?

Comment: @ChristianMatt Any number a

Comment: For real numbers $a$, you cannot use induction.

Comment: @quasi it works for both those $a$, $a^2$ is not included in the numerator of the fraction, there are no parenthesis around it.

Comment: @egreg The second one

Comment: @Will Fisher: Yes, I just realized that.

Comment: @GerardL.: If you're allowing real values of a, not just integers. you need to assume $a \ge 1$.

Comment: @egreg Can you edit the LaTeX for me? I don't know how to change the format.

Comment: @GerardL. Is it correct?

Comment: @egreg It is, thank you!

Comment: I posted an incorrect answer, and the error was pointed out, so I deleted it.

Comment: Note that $a^2-a-1\geq 0$ for $a\geq \phi=\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}$ so you only need to show the inequality for $a\in (1,\phi)$.

Answer (score 5):

Let $f:[1,\infty) \to \mathbb{R}$ be defined by

$$f(a) = a^2 - a  - 1 + \frac{1}{a^a - a + 1}$$

The goal is to show $f(a) \ge 0$ for all $a \in [1,\infty)$.

First suppose $a \ge 2$. Then

\begin{align*}
f(a) &= a^2 - a  - 1 + \frac{1}{a^a - a + 1}\\[6pt]
&> a^2 - a  - 1\\[6pt] 
&\ge 2^2 - 2 - 1 = 1\\[6pt]
&> 0\\
\end{align*}

Next suppose $1 \le a < 2$. Then

\begin{align*}
f(a) &= a^2 - a  - 1 + \frac{1}{a^a - a + 1}\\[6pt]
&\ge a^2 - a  - 1 + \frac{1}{a^2 - a + 1}\\[6pt]
&= \left(a^2 - a + 1 + \frac{1}{a^2 - a + 1}\right) - 2\\[6pt] 
&\ge 2 - 2\qquad\text{[by AM-GM]}\\[6pt] 
&=0\\
\end{align*}

Therefore $f(a) \ge 0$  for all $a \in [1,\infty)$, as required.

Comment: Nice use of AM-GM! (+1)

Comment: But this proof doesn show it for all numbers

Comment: @GerardL. this is because it is not true for all numbers... you can check the plot of $f(a)$ in my answer to see that it is not true for $a\in[0,1)$ and your inequality is anyway not defined for every irrational $a<0$.

Answer (score 1):

This is probably not the most complete answer but it (somehow) proves the claim.

First, note that for $a\geq 1$, we have $$a^a-a+1 \geq a^a \geq a\geq 1$$ so that $\frac{1}{a^a-a+1}\geq 0$.

Now, $a^2-a+1$ is a convex parabola and $a^2-a-1=0$ for $a=\phi$ where $\phi$ is the golden ratio $\phi = \frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}$. It follows that
$$ a^2+\frac{1}{a^a-a+1}-(a+1)\geq a^2-a-1 \geq 0 \qquad \forall a \in [\phi,\infty).$$

I propose to conclude with a proof by drawing, indeed for $a\in[1,\phi)$ the graph of the continuous function $f(a)=a^2+\frac{1}{a^a-a+1}-a-1$ is given by:
[image]
and therefore your inequality is true for every $a\geq 1$.